# "Unknown column in 'field list'" any idea why i get It?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Any idea why I am getting this exception ?

My create Table looks like this:

```
string.Format("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{0}`  ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,  `CAMXTime`  DATETIME  ,`Message` LONGTEXT , PRIMARY KEY  (`id`));", GlobalVariables.CamxmassagesTable);
```

And insert statement looks like

```
string.Format("INSERT INTO `{0}` (`CAMXTime` , `Message`) VALUES (`{1}`,`{2}`);", GlobalVariables.CamxmassagesTable, newNode.Item1, newNode.Item2);
```

`newNode.Item1` is from type `DATETIME`.
`newNode.Item2 i`s a `string`.

Any idea ?

Comment: I'm frowning upon this code. It gives an unprepared reader a false sense of using a parametric query and being protected from sql injections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using single quotes in your values (and, of course, escaping them in the first place). So the `INSERT` statement should be:

```
string.Format(
    "INSERT INTO `{0}` (`CAMXTime` , `Message`) VALUES ('{1}','{2}');", // ` to '
    GlobalVariables.CamxmassagesTable,
    newNode.Item1.Replace("'", "''"),
    newNode.Item2.Replace("'", "''")
);
```

Not that you should use that way to execute SQL queries *nor* to escape values, but it's marginally better.

**Edit**: Use parametrized queries.

Comment: now I am getting following exception: "Incorrect datetime value: '6/18/2011 4:07:57 PM' for column 'CAMXTime' at row 1"

Comment: Any answer that *doesn't* say "use paramterized queries" is wrong, IMO.

Comment: @Night Walker: That date format isn't accepted, use another one or use Date.Parse first, then use the correct round-trip format string: `myDate.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'fff")`